# PHP same event for multiple dates

Tags: date, database-design

I am trying to create an events calendar that can have multiple dates for the same (entertainer) What would be the best way to do this?

I already have working code that will add an entertainer name, a photo, a description, a date and a venue and I can pull them out a database table when needed.

The above works for one date.

However, the same entertainer may work the same venue several times a year, and currently that would mean entering the photo, date, description, venue, entertainer name for each performance date.

Is there a way to add multiple dates to this record, or would it be a better solution to add an entertainers details into an entertainers table (name,photo,description etc. (so only entered once) and then add a date and a venue, and choose an already entered entertainer somehow?

Comment: You need two tables - one for the entertainer, and a separate one for their engagements. And a separate one for each venue, so three really. The engagements table will then just need the date, entertainer id and venue id, and you can establish rules to ensure that you can't book the same entertainer on the same date at multiple venues, or (if appropriate) book multiple entertainers at the same venue on the same date. The term is Database Normalisation.